# How can I use a list in a for in range loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

```
consonant_letters = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']
for x in range(9999):
    for y in range(consonant_letters):
        for z in range(consonant_letters):
            for a in range(consonant_letters):
                print(f'{x} {y} {z} {a}')
```

*And what I get is this

> TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

*I'm trying to print all the numbers in the Spanish License Plate system, transform it into a list and lastly, do an input function where the user enters a certain license plate, and the program tells him how many license plates there are until this license plate system ends.

*Edit: I found out now the only thing I have left and can't figure out is how to formulate the input function. Here's the solution:

```
consonant_letters = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',    
'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']

for x in range(10000):
    break
    if x < 1000 and x > 99:
        x = f"0{x}"
    elif x < 100 and x > 9:
        x = f"00{x}"
    elif x < 10:
        x = f"000{x}"
    for y in consonant_letters:
        for z in consonant_letters:
            for a in consonant_letters:
                print(f'{x} {y} {z} {a}')
```

*I tried introducing the input function so the user can introduce a certain license plate number and I will detect if it exists but there's a problem. 
Here's what I tried:

```
`consonant_letters = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L',      
'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']
for x in range(10000):
if x < 1000 and x > 99:
    x = f"0{x}"
elif x < 100 and x > 9:
    x = f"00{x}"
elif x < 10:
    x = f"000{x}"
for y in consonant_letters:
    for z in consonant_letters:
        for a in consonant_letters:
            list_1 = f'{x} {y}{z}{a}'
            license_plate_user = input("Write the license plate: ")
            print(license_plate_user in list_1)`
```

*When I introduce any other license plate that's not 0000 BBB (the first one) it says False. I know this means that the loop gets executed only one time, but I don't know how to fix it.

*Edit; I figured out how to get the loop executed and then formulate the input but I have one more question left. Is there an operation I can write knowing a specific license plate to know how many there are left?

```
consonant_letters = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',   
'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']
for x in range(10000):
if x < 1000 and x > 99:
    x = f"0{x}"
elif x < 100 and x > 9:
    x = f"00{x}"
elif x < 10:
    x = f"000{x}"
for y in consonant_letters:
    for z in consonant_letters:
        for a in consonant_letters:
            list1 = f'{x} {y}{z}{a}'
            if "9999 ZZZ" in list1:
                license_plate_user = input("Write the license plate: ")
                license_plate_user in list1
                if license_plate_user:
                    print("Operation I do not know yet")
                else:
                    print("Wrong values")
```

*Edit: I found a way but it's not working and I don't know why:

```
consonant_letters = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
'N', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']
total_number_of_license_plates = 80000000
for x in range(10000):
    if x < 1000 and x > 99:
        x = f"0{x}"
    elif x < 100 and x > 9:
        x = f"00{x}"
    elif x < 10:
        x = f"000{x}"
    for y in consonant_letters:
        for z in consonant_letters:
            for a in consonant_letters:
                list1 = f'{x} {y}{z}{a}'
                if "9999 ZZZ" in list1:
                    license_plate_user = input("Write the license   
plate: ")
                    license_plate_user in list1
                    if license_plate_user:
                        print(list1.index(license_plate_user))
                        license_plates_left = 
total_number_of_license_plates - list1.index(license_plate_user)
                        print(f'There are {license_plates_left} license 
plates left')
                    else:
                        print("Wrong values")
```

And what I get is:

> ValueError: substring not found

Comment: You probably meant `for y in consonant_letters:`.

Comment: Just don't use range, use the list as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) accept integer or integers as inputs. In case you are not sure how to use given word you might launch python intrepeter and ask it - in this case:

```
help(range)
```

your code will work after replacing all `range(consonant_letters)` with `consonant_letters` but I want to note that your task is ideal place to use `itertools.product`. Consider following example:

```
import itertools
x = ['A','B','C']
for x1,x2,x3 in itertools.product(x,repeat=3):
    print(f'{x1} {x2} {x3}')
```

Output:

```
A A A
A A B
A A C
A B A
A B B
A B C
A C A
A C B
A C C
B A A
B A B
B A C
B B A
B B B
B B C
B C A
B C B
B C C
C A A
C A B
C A C
C B A
C B B
C B C
C C A
C C B
C C C
```

As you can see it allow you to use one `for`-loop instead of (in this case) 3 nested `for`-loops.

Comment: So you're basically saying if I use the "itertools.product" it's the same result but simpler right? I'm sorry if my questions are pretty obvious but I'm new and I'm trying my best.

Comment: Yes, note also order - using `help(itertools.product)` wording *cycle in a manner similar to an odometer (with the rightmost element changing on every iteration).* Thus if you replace `['A','B','C']` in my example with `['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']` you would get all numbers from `0 0 0` up to `9 9 9` (inclusive) ordered ascending.

Comment: 100% understood. I have one last question. If I've figured out how to know how many license plates there are left from a license plate introduced by the user (input function), but it doesn't work? Please check out my latest update on this post and if you could help me that would be great because I'm stuck right now. @Daweo

Answer (score 1):

you can't use range() with list use this:

```
for x in range(9999):
    for y in consonant_letters:
        for z in consonant_letters:
            for a in consonant_letters:
                print(f'{x} {y} {z} {a}')
```

Comment: @Guillermo - Amir's answer will solve it for you. Reason: `range` requires an integer as input. So you could also use something like: `for y in range(len(consonant_letters))`, which returns an integer. But you can also iterate over a list directly, (such as Amir is showing).

Comment: And if I want to add an input function that lets the user introduce a certain combination of numbers and letters, in this case, 4 numbers and 3 letters, so I can print how many licenses plates there are left? (the number, not the license)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with *one* loop:

```
from itertools import product

for x, (y, z, a) in product(range(9999), product(consonant_letters, repeat=3)):
    print(f'{x} {y} {z} {a}')
```

Comment: And if I want to add an input function that lets the user introduce a certain combination of numbers and letters, in this case, 4 numbers and 3 letters, so I can print how many licenses plates there are left? (the number, not the license)